# IMAGENET - Is it possible to train caffe alexnet with image contains only 10 classes

Tags: caffe, conv-neural-network, imagenet

I used `caffe/examples/cifar10` to train models for classification and I want to use this result to do visualization. But I found that cifar10 images are all `32*32` which is too small to do per unit visualization. Now I want to try to use another dataset which is Imagenet.

But in my case instead of a thousand class I want only ten of the class just like cifar-10. I found that the data IMAGENET provide is too big to download it and extract those ten class. Is there any possible way that I could use the `full url image` downloaded from the official imagenet website. and download the selected 10 classes to store in my disk? Because I don't see any label on the text file(image full url).

Answer (score 0):

If you poke around, I believe that you'll find a text file that lists each URL, along with the label for that URL -- an integer in the range 0-999.

However, I don't know of a site that maps ILSVRC data classes to CIFAR classes.  I poked around on the Internet for a while and came up with nothing.  You may wind up having to examine all 1000 classes and create your own mapping.